# Create an empty data.frame and fill each row in R after looping

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, lapply

I want to fill a `data.frame` by rows. My results are vectors such as

```
spp = c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3")
roc = c(0.74, 0.75, 0.76)
prc = c(0.45, 0.46, 0.47)
```

I'm posting the results as vectors because they came from a prior loop, so I'm trying to fill by loop.

What I'm trying to do returns the ''replacement has 0 rows'' error.

An ideal result would look like

```
data.frame(spp = c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3),
           roc = c("0.74, 0.75, 0.76),
           pcr = c(0.45, 0.46, 0.47))
```

So that each row is filled iteratively, one by one.

How can I proceed?

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: After the loop, I have three values that I want to append to a data.frame.  One is the species name, "sp1", the other is a roc value obtained from a function auc(precrec_obj)$aucs[1], and the other is a prc value obtain from the same function auc(precrec_obj)$aucs[2]. My final data.frame , ideally, would have 449 rows, one for each species name, filled with the name of the species, the roc, and the prc. But since I'm doing this one by one this df needs to be filled one by one too. If I'm being confused please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach  is to generate the structure of your data.frame prior to looping, and then within each iteration of the loop over species (say `sp`) that produces the single values for roc (say, `roc_i`) and prc (say, `prc_i`), add them to the data.frame:

```
result=structure(list(spp = character(), roc=float(),prc=float()),class = "data.frame")

for(sp %in% unique(species)) {
  #code that produces roc_i, prc_i for sp
  ...
  # add row to result
  result = rbind(result, data.frame(spp=sp,roc=roc_i, prc=prc_i)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I explained it a little bit better above, I think. Basically, I'm looping each unique species from a set of 449 species and obtaining a value for roc and prc one at a time. Since my loop starts with the species one by one, ideally, the first line of my data.frame or something must have 3 columns (spp, roc, prc) and one row. After I loop for the second species, then 3 columns with 2 rows...until it ends.

Comment: okay, does the above help?